# Find latest received amounts from current amounts

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the latest received amount from a table that monitors the current amount of an item.

Currently the current amount totals are stored, instead of each <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> transaction. When a report is generated, I need to see the current, latest received, latest removed amounts. Then be able to do the same in a given time frame. Such as items received in the month of January, using the omitted timestamp column.

table layout

```
 id | item_id | amount  
 1  |  20     |   5    # +5  (initial)
 2  |  30     |   1    # +1  (initial)
 3  |  20     |   20   # +15 
 4  |  15     |   10   # +10 (initial/latest)
 5  |  20     |   25   # +5  (latest)
 6  |  20     |   4    # -21 
 7  |  30     |   2    # -1  
 8  |  30     |   5    # +3  (latest)
 9  |  15     |   2    # -8  
10  |  15     |   1    # -1
```

**Example Query**

```
SELECT
   t1.item_id,
   t1.amount as amount,
   IFNULL(t2.amount, 0) as previous_amount,
   IFNULL(t1.amount - IFNULL(t2.amount, 0), NULL) as received_amount
FROM
   items AS t1
LEFT JOIN
   items AS t2
ON
    t1.item_id = t2.item_id
AND
    t1.id > t2.id #Get the record before the current t1.id
```

**Returned Results**

```
item_id | amount | previous_amount | received_amount | matching_ids    
20      | 5      |    0            |    5            |    1, NULL    
30      | 1      |    0            |    1            |    2, NULL    
20      | 20     |    5            |    15           |    3, 1    
15      | 10     |    0            |    10           |    4, NULL    
20      | 25     |    5            |    20           |    5, 1    
20      | 25     |    20           |    5            |    5, 3    
20      | 4      |    5            |    -1           |    6, 1    
20      | 4      |    20           |    -16          |    6, 3    
20      | 4      |    25           |    -21          |    6, 5    
30      | 2      |    1            |    1            |    7, 2    
30      | 5      |    1            |    4            |    8, 2    
30      | 5      |    2            |    3            |    8, 7    
15      | 2      |    10           |    -8           |    9, 4    
15      | 1      |    10           |    -9           |    10, 4    
15      | 1      |    2            |    -1           |    10, 9
```

Desired result is only the latest received amounts if any.

**Desired Result**

```
#last_received_amount = (t1.amount - t2.amount)
item_id | latest_received_amount | matching_ids
   20   |    5                   |   5, 3
   15   |    10                  |   4, null
   30   |    3                   |   8, 7
```

The query is intended to be used as an interim fix, until it is refactored using individual transactions.

Comment: What determines what the last amount received was? I see no date column

Comment: you want to find last received amounts for all categories am i right?

Comment: @Venkat categories are variable.

Comment: What is the desired result based on the data you provided? Explain more...

Comment: @Evan Amount received is based off of current state. Date doesn't apply. Each entry is based off of current amounts. So if I have 20 and I received 5 the new entry in the database would be 25. Where as if I removed 10 from that latest entry the next value would be 15. This gives me a transaction for each amount received and removed. There is however a unix_timestamp for the creation of each record.

Comment: @tombom I just need the latest received amounts if any.

Comment: How do you know when an amount is received and when removed? And like I said, please add another table with the desired result. It's not clear at all your question.

Comment: This question is still making no sense to me. Looking at your joins, I don't even see how data is being returned.

Comment: @tombom ID can be used as the point in time reference as I use transactions to insert the records. I updated with the desired results.

Comment: What does category_id have to do with all this?

Comment: @tombom It is used in my actual query to filter the resulting items

Comment: @Evan I updated the original post to show you the results from the example table and my SQL Example.

Comment: @fyrye I'm working on it ..

Comment: @fyrye you updated your question - explain to me how you get `5` for the last received amount for item_id of 20 ?

Comment: @fyrye I see the first three amounts amount to 50, and the last amount is `4` - so how do you get `5` from that?

Comment: From the data I assume the highest `id` is considered the latest entry. I wouldn't assume so, because that may not be true.... but I see no other way in the current data.

Comment: @Wrikken Yes, that has been established somewhere up there ^^

Comment: No harm in explicitly stating that even auto incrementing columns are not there to give an order or relative point-in-time of entries. Auto-ids are for identification, nothing else, or it might bite you...

Comment: @Wrikken Yes I know, but for the given example that is what I am using, I do have a unix_timestamp for the actual point in time reference, but id suffices in retrieving the equivalent results.

Comment: @Evan Looking at the data incrementally the current amount of item_id 20 is 4 the previous amount was id 5 | amount 25 which means it was removed the previous amount to id 5 | amount 25 was id 3 | amount 20 which means we received 5. So the last received amount was 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 times the table in the query (2 to get the latest `id`,2 to get the `id` before that):

## latest mutations

```
SELECT
   t1.item_id,
   t1.amount as amount,
   IFNULL(t3.amount, 0) as previous_amount,
   IFNULL(t1.amount - IFNULL(t3.amount, 0), NULL) as received_amount,
   CONCAT_WS(', ',t1.id, t3.id)
FROM items t1
LEFT JOIN items t2
  ON  t1.item_id = t2.item_id
  AND t2.id > t1.id
LEFT JOIN items t3
  ON  t1.item_id = t3.item_id
  AND t3.id != t1.id
LEFT JOIN items t4
  ON  t1.item_id = t4.item_id
  AND t4.id > t3.id
  AND t4.id != t1.id
WHERE 
    t1.category_id IN( '1', '2', '3' )
    AND t2.id IS NULL
    AND t4.id IS NULL;


+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| item_id | amount | previous_amount | received_amount | CONCAT_WS(', ',t1.id, t3.id) |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
|      20 |      4 |              25 |             -21 | 6, 5                         |
|      30 |      5 |               2 |               3 | 8, 7                         |
|      15 |      1 |               2 |              -1 | 10, 9                        |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

## positive mutations

```
  SELECT
    t1.item_id,
    t1.amount as amount,
    IFNULL(t2.amount, 0) as previous_amount,
    IFNULL(t1.amount - IFNULL(t2.amount, 0), NULL) as received_amount,
    CONCAT_WS(', ',t1.id, t2.id)
  FROM items t1
  LEFT JOIN items t2
    ON  t1.item_id = t2.item_id
    AND t2.id < t1.id
    AND t2.amount < t1.amount
  LEFT JOIN items t3
    ON  t2.item_id = t3.item_id
    AND t3.id > t2.id
    AND t3.id < t1.id
  LEFT JOIN items noprev
    ON  t1.item_id = noprev.item_id
    AND noprev.id < t1.id
    AND noprev.amount > t1.amount
  WHERE
      t1.category_id IN( '1', '2', '3' )
      AND t3.id IS NULL
      AND (noprev.id IS NULL OR t2.id IS NOT NULL)

+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| item_id | amount | previous_amount | received_amount | CONCAT_WS(', ',t1.id, t2.id) |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
|      20 |      5 |               0 |               5 | 1                            |
|      30 |      1 |               0 |               1 | 2                            |
|      20 |     20 |               5 |              15 | 3, 1                         |
|      15 |     10 |               0 |              10 | 4                            |
|      20 |     25 |              20 |               5 | 5, 3                         |
|      30 |      2 |               1 |               1 | 7, 2                         |
|      30 |      5 |               2 |               3 | 8, 7                         |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

## latest positive mutations

```
SELECT increases.item_id, increases.amount, increases.previous_amount,increases.received_amount,increases.ids
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.item_id,
    t1.amount as amount,
    IFNULL(t2.amount, 0) as previous_amount,
    IFNULL(t1.amount - IFNULL(t2.amount, 0), NULL) as received_amount,
    CONCAT_WS(', ',t1.id, t2.id) as ids
  FROM items t1
  LEFT JOIN items t2
    ON  t1.item_id = t2.item_id
    AND t2.id < t1.id
    AND t2.amount < t1.amount
  LEFT JOIN items t3
    ON  t2.item_id = t3.item_id
    AND t3.id > t2.id 
    AND t3.id < t1.id
  LEFT JOIN items noprev
    ON  t1.item_id = noprev.item_id
    AND noprev.id < t1.id
    AND noprev.amount > t1.amount
  WHERE 
      t1.category_id IN( '1', '2', '3' )
      AND t3.id IS NULL
      AND (noprev.id IS NULL OR t2.id IS NOT NULL)
) increases
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.item_id
  FROM items t1
  JOIN items t2
    ON  t1.item_id = t2.item_id
    AND t2.id < t1.id
    AND t2.amount < t1.amount
  LEFT JOIN items t3
    ON  t2.item_id = t3.item_id
    AND t3.id > t2.id 
    AND t3.id < t1.id
  WHERE 
      t1.category_id IN( '1', '2', '3' )
      AND t3.id IS NULL
) later_increases
  ON later_increases.item_id = increases.item_id
  AND later_increases.id > increases.id
WHERE later_increases.id IS NULL;

+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------+
| item_id | amount | previous_amount | received_amount | ids  |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------+
|      15 |     10 |               0 |              10 | 4    |
|      20 |     25 |              20 |               5 | 5, 3 |
|      30 |      5 |               2 |               3 | 8, 7 |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------+
```

Which illustrates.... you might want to use temporary tables for this one.

Comment: The negative indicates removed items. I need the latest positive/received items. See desired results. I updated the table with comments to show math of items and latest received. As well the query in reverse should return the removed items.

Comment: I also removed the category id to be less obscure. I was going to use my full query for the example but decided to be more simplistic. Seems what I need can't be accomplished with mySQL easily, so I may need to add received/removed columns. I came close with a subquery order by id DESC but the records are still off.

Comment: Hmf, only positive mutations... would be a lot easier if that was in the table :) I'll see what I can do, by I predict even more joins on itself needed...

Comment: There you go, I can't seem the times the table is used under 7, maybe someone else might, but temporary tables seem the way to go here (or storing the mutation in `items` rather then the new value: it's a lot easier to calculate the current amount then whether an amount is bigger then its predecessor).

Comment: Yea I am going to be storing the received/removed the issue is that I am currently developing that system and needed this as an interim. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: The query I came up with was a subquery in the selected columns of an order by join and group by statement.

Comment: Well, seeing as they're integers, you could indeed cheat a bit with example 2 (positives) & `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(... SEPARATOR ';' ORDER BY id),';',1)` or similar constructs. Atrocious to look at, but good enough for an interim-systen,